# Assign getters to data property -> data property doesn't change

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to assign a getters to my data "lang". It works but when I change the language (and the value of my getters changes too), my "lang" value does not change.

```
data() {
      return {
                lang: this.$store.getters['lang/locale'],
                loading: false,
                errored: false,
            }
        },
```

how to do that?

My lang.js :

```
// state
export const state = () => ({
  locale: process.env.appLocale,
  locales: {
    'fr': 'FR',
    'en': 'EN'
  }
})

// getters
export const getters = {
  locale: state => state.locale,
  locales: state => state.locales
}

// mutations
export const mutations = {
  SET_LOCALE (state, { locale }) {
    state.locale = locale
  }
}

// actions
export const actions = {
  setLocale ({ commit }, { locale }) {
    commit('SET_LOCALE', { locale })

    Cookies.set('locale', locale, { expires: 365 })
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a computed property instead of `data`. See https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed method:

```
computed:{
Lang(){
  return this.$store.getters['lang/locale']
}
```

and use the Lang in your template.